# How do I restore my macOS keychain from iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, keychain

I currently have iCloud Keychain enabled on my devices but am having [trouble with my iCloud keychain on my Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/421182/4395). It seems like a reasonable thing to try would be to delete the iCloud keychain on my Mac and then restore it from iCloud, but I'm not sure whether this is safe or would preserve all of my keychain entries.

What is the correct procedure for restoring iCloud Keychain on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Open System Preferences > Apple ID.
[image]

Untick the Keychain box and follow any on-screen instructions. Give the computer a couple of minutes, then restart. The iCloud keychain is now deleted. Go back to System Preferences > Apple ID, and re-tick the keychain box. Follow all on-screen instructions, wait a couple of minutes to sync, and your iCloud keychain will be fixed. If you had any entries not synced due to issues syncing, these will be lost. If you are having trouble loading iCloud entires from the web, then your issue will probably get fixed.

Comment: And just to be sure: I won't lose anything that's in my iCloud keychain in the cloud when I do this. In other words, the end result will be that I have the same keychain on my Mac that I have on my iPhone, correct?

Comment: Also: When I do this, what should I expect to see in Keychain Access? I'll still have 'login', of course, and 'iCloud' will be gone, but will I then have a 'local' keychain? If so what will be in it and how will it be handled when I re-enable iCloud keychain?

Comment: And (sorry): If I follow these steps _without_ restarting, FWIW, I by iCloud keychain becomes a 'local' keychain and then re-enabling iCloud keychain fails to fix the problem. Perhaps restarting makes the difference, but perhaps I should also delete the 'local' keychain? (I'm not sure where it is.)

Comment: @orome After this, your mac's keychain will be the same as your iPhone's (nothing will be deleted). When you untick the box, the keychain becomes a "Local Items" keychain. Restarting is not necessary, it will just clear up issues, therefore I recommend it. It doesn't do anything to the keychain, though. I am not sure if it is safe to delete all entries in Local Items - it could delete mac-specific keychain entries that arent loaded into iCloud, but it also could be fine. Someone else needs to figure that out.

Comment: Seems like restart must be necessary in this case since toggling the iCloud keychain alone doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: In that case, disable, wait, restart, wait, enable

Comment: No luck. Tired this several times and it made no difference.